# different user group can not upload file in the server

Tags: permissions, configuration

I have a CentOS server running in Thailand, and I'm in Canada.

The guy at the computer center who set up the server for me doesn't really understand much about linux and left me off an issue to solve myself.

I just moved from Mac Server to Linux server, and the first thing I'm facing a problem now is

```
`file name` has failed to upload due to an error
The uploaded file could not be moved to `location name`
```

So what happen is that I knew from my experiences of these problem is all about permissions.

So I go ahead and checked on my whole folder and found that everything in the folder permission is like `myusername` `mygroupname`
then I checked the `httpd` file in the server and it is default to 
`apache` `apache`.

My question is that how can I make my user to be in the same group with `apache` group so that I don't have to have any problem about uploading, changing data in my file....?

But without having to affect other user in the same server.

I'm holding Administrator account, but not root account, but I can change stuff on the server root no problem.

When I was with godaddy.com there never been any problem about the permission and I wish I know how they configure that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo usermod -G apache myusername` will add `myusername` to the `apache` group. When you say that you have administrative but not root access to the server, I'm hoping that what you mean is that you have full sudo access, and just can't log in as root.

Alternately, if you don't have sudo access but have some other means to update files, you can edit `/etc/group` and change the row that starts `apache:`, adding `,myusername` at the end, like:

```
apache:x:502:apache,otherusername,myusername
```